# Stormpath with hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, stormpath

I have the following Entity:

```
import com.stormpath.sdk.account.Account;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Stock {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;
  private String ticker;
  private Double lastPrice;

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
  private Date createdAt;

  // Account comes from Stormpath (login manager) so it's not persisted in my database. How should I define this relation?
//  @ManyToOne
//  private Account account;
```

My users can have many stocks. But I'm managing the users using Stormpath, so the users are not actually in my database. Is there a way to use hibernate with the Account, so I can have a @ManyToOne relationship, since the account is not at my database?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same isuue . did you find a solution for this ?